# How to groupby using lodash by ignoring minor difference

Tags: lodash

I have data in following form. And I am using loadash for groupby by row. However loadash groupby is returning groups based on row values, I am expecting it should ignore minor difference of 1 value between rows and then group. ex. it should add items with row 9 and row 10 in one group. What should I return from groupby callback function which will groupby on properties by including neighboring values.

```
[
  {
    "row": 9,
    "city": "Camas"
  },
  {
    "row": 9,
    "city": "Kersey"
  },
  {
    "row": 6,
    "city": "Ebro"
  },
  {
    "row": 10,
    "city": "Orick"
  },
  {
    "row": 2,
    "city": "Bonanza"
  },
  {
    "row": 6,
    "city": "Rowe"
  },
  {
    "row": 5,
    "city": "Walland"
  }
]
```

Expected Output

```
 {
    2: [
        {
            "row": 2,
            "city": "Bonanza"
        },
    ],
    5: [
        {
            "row": 6,
            "city": "Ebro"
        },
        {
            "row": 6,
            "city": "Rowe"
        },
        {
            "row": 5,
            "city": "Walland"
        }
    ],
    9: [{
        "row": 9,
        "city": "Camas"
    },
    {
        "row": 9,
        "city": "Kersey"
    },
    {
        "row": 10,
        "city": "Orick"
    }
    ]
}
```

Comment: [lodash#groupBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#groupBy) returns an object wherein keys represents a unique value from the keys of the collection that you provide or a custom key that you generate from the iteratee that you provide. From your instructions, I don't see a way to group them in a certain criteria (key), can you provide an expected output?

Comment: @ryeballar, I updated the question, added expected output aswell. The keys in returned object is not important and anything can be acceptable.

Comment: what will happen if we add a row: 7 and a row: 8?

Comment: @ryeballar, There wont be such condition, there can be maximum 2 points error(difference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to solve this problem is to [sort](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#sortBy) the collection by `row` in ascending order, and then [reduce](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#reduce) the sorted collection by combining items with a row difference of one and simply assigning those who doesn't have one.

```
var result = _(data)
  .sortBy('row')
  .reduce(function(group, item) {
    var nIndex = item.row - 1;
    var value = [item];
    if (group[nIndex]) {
      group[nIndex] = value.concat(group[nIndex]);
    } else {
      group[item.row] = value;
    }
    return group;
  }, {});
```

```js
var data = [{
    "row": 9,
    "city": "Camas"
  },
  {
    "row": 9,
    "city": "Kersey"
  },
  {
    "row": 6,
    "city": "Ebro"
  },
  {
    "row": 10,
    "city": "Orick"
  },
  {
    "row": 2,
    "city": "Bonanza"
  },
  {
    "row": 6,
    "city": "Rowe"
  },
  {
    "row": 5,
    "city": "Walland"
  }
];

var result = _(data)
  .sortBy('row')
  .reduce(function(group, item) {
    var nIndex = item.row - 1;
    var value = [item];
    if (group[nIndex]) {
      group[nIndex] = value.concat(group[nIndex]);
    } else {
      group[item.row] = value;
    }
    return group;
  }, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
body>div {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

The solution above can also be implemented using vanilla JS [Array#sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort?v=example) and [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce?v=example)

```
var result = data
  .sort(function(v1, v2) {
    return v1.row - v2.row;
  })
  .reduce(function(group, item) {
    var nIndex = item.row - 1;
    var value = [item];
    if (group[nIndex]) {
      group[nIndex] = value.concat(group[nIndex]);
    } else {
      group[item.row] = value;
    }
    return group;
  }, {});
```

```js
var data = [{
    "row": 9,
    "city": "Camas"
  },
  {
    "row": 9,
    "city": "Kersey"
  },
  {
    "row": 6,
    "city": "Ebro"
  },
  {
    "row": 10,
    "city": "Orick"
  },
  {
    "row": 2,
    "city": "Bonanza"
  },
  {
    "row": 6,
    "city": "Rowe"
  },
  {
    "row": 5,
    "city": "Walland"
  }
];

var result = data
  .sort(function(v1, v2) {
    return v1.row - v2.row;
  })
  .reduce(function(group, item) {
    var nIndex = item.row - 1;
    var value = [item];
    if (group[nIndex]) {
      group[nIndex] = value.concat(group[nIndex]);
    } else {
      group[item.row] = value;
    }
    return group;
  }, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
body>div {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```